# Access venue details using userless access

Tags: foursquare

Anyone know if is possible to access venue details https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID
from userless access?

I keep getting the error below:

`{
    "meta": {
        "code": 400,
        "errorType": "invalid_auth",
        "errorDetail": "Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html for details."
    },
    "response": {}
}`

Answer (score 0):

Yup. You need to include the parameters `client_id` and `client_secret` in your request. See https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#userless and https://developer.foursquare.com/start/search for more details.