# Foursquare "Missing access credentials" for venue search with Client ID and Client Secret

Tags: ios, foursquare

I am trying to search for venues from the foursquare API's venue endpoint which can be done without authentication with a client id and client secret. I have generated those in the foursquare website and my request url string looks like this...

```
NSString *requestString = @"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=New+Delhi&intent=browse@radius=10000&limit=10&query=pizza+hut&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=YYYY&v=DATEVERIFIED";
```

where XXXX and YYYY are my client ID and client secret respectively.

I don't know what I am doing wrong but I get this response

```
{
 meta =     {
 code = 400;
 errorDetail = "Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html for details.";
 errorType = "invalid_auth";
};
response =     {
};
```

Please help me out...

PS: I am a first time developer and have already looked in stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959129/access-venue-details-using-userless-access) but that didn't help me. So please consider encouraging this question instead of negative voting it.

Comment: Did you look at the link in the error message?

Comment: Yes. Thats the first thing I did. Please have a look at the **Userless Access** section of that link. Contacted Foursquare. They gave me a link to raise a support request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work here. I changed the @radius to &radius, and v=DATEVERIFIED to v=20140715

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=New+Delhi&intent=browse&radius=10000&limit=10&query=pizza+hut&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=YYYY&v=20140715

Comment: PERFECT! that worked for me. That... `@radius` was a very silly mistake but there was more wrong that i couldn't spot out. So i just copy-pasted your URL and inserted my client ID & client secret and now it works fine. Thanks a million!

Sorry can't vote up cause haven't got enough reputation points.

Comment: BTW, does the arrangement of various fields in the url have any impact?